# What should be public ip adress for raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I see many tutorials on how to run a node server on raspberry pi. But dont see how to set configuration for public IP. Fortunately, I have access to the x.x.x.x:port where is ssh.

Should be the same IP number for my public website??

When I check

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

I get a different IP number.

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong??

Comment: Your raspberry pi likely connects to your home router. Your home router likely has your home's external facing IP. What you need to do is configure your router in your router's settings "Port Forwarding" menu to allow whatever Port from external to route to your internal Raspberry Pi's IP. Then when external traffic hits your home's IP on that port, the traffic will be forwarded, via your router, to your Pi. Once that happens, know that this is a path for external folks to get into your network so any exploits/bugs/zero-days/security holes are present could cause a bad day.

Comment: Taking a step back, the IP of your Pi is the IP handed out by your router. It's your PI's LAN ip and is only good for your local network in your home. Your device that is facing the internet (likely your router) has your 1 external IP address (your WAN address). You likely only get that one IP from your ISP so people that need to connect to your pi would have to head to that IP and your router would be configured by you to pass that traffic to your Pi's LAN IP. I hope that makes enough sense that you can figure out next steps for whatever you are trying to do.